# Consume non-overlapping vector chunks, and combine results

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, rust

I'm trying to speed up an expensive computation on a large vector by using threads. My function consumes a vector, computes a vector of new values (it doesn't aggregate, but input order has to be retained), and returns it. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to spawn threads, assign vector slices to each, and then collect and combine the results.

```
// tunable
const NUMTHREADS: i32 = 4;

fn f(val: i32) -> i32 {
    // expensive computation
    let res = val + 1;
    res

}

fn main() {
    // choose an odd number of elements
    let orig = (1..14).collect::<Vec<i32>>();
    let mut result: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec!();
    let mut flat: Vec<i32> = Vec::with_capacity(orig.len());
    // split into slices
    for chunk in orig.chunks(orig.len() / NUMTHREADS as usize) {
        result.push(
            chunk.iter().map(|&digit|
                f(digit)).collect()
            );
    };
    // flatten result vector
    for subvec in result.iter() {
        for elem in subvec.iter() {
            flat.push(elem.to_owned());
        }
    }
    println!("Flattened result: {:?}", flat);
}
```

The threaded computation should be taking place between `for chunk…` and `// flatten …`, but I can't find many simple examples of spawning x threads, assigning chunks sequentially, and returning the newly-computed vector out of the thread and into a container so it can be flattened. Do I have to wrap `orig.chunks()` in an `Arc`, and manually grab each chunk in a loop? Do I have to pass `f` into each thread? Will I have to use a B-Tree to ensure that input and output order match? Can I just use [`simple_parallel`](http://huonw.github.io/simple_parallel/simple_parallel/index.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is an ideal application for the unstable [`thread::scoped()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scoped.html):

```rust
#![feature(scoped)]
use std::thread::{self, JoinGuard};

// tunable
const NUMTHREADS: i32 = 4;

fn f(val: i32) -> i32 {
    // expensive computation
    let res = val + 1;
    res
}

fn main() {
    // choose an odd number of elements
    let orig: Vec<i32> = (1..14).collect();

    let mut guards: Vec<JoinGuard<Vec<i32>>> = vec!();

    // split into slices
    for chunk in orig.chunks(orig.len() / NUMTHREADS as usize) {
        let g = thread::scoped(move || chunk.iter().cloned().map(f).collect());
        guards.push(g);
    };

    // collect the results
    let mut result: Vec<i32> = Vec::with_capacity(orig.len());
    for g in guards {
        result.extend(g.join().into_iter());
    }

    println!("Flattened result: {:?}", result);
}
```

It is unstable and won't likely be stabilized in this form because it has an inherent flaw (you can find more [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24292)). As far as I can see, `simple_parallel` is just an extension of this approach - it hides the fiddling with `JoinGuards` and also can be used in stable Rust (probably with some `unsafe`ty, I believe). It is not recommended for the general use, however, as its docs suggest.

Of course, you can use `thread::spawn()`, but then you will need to clone each chunk so it could be moved into each thread:

```rust
use std::thread::{self, JoinHandle};

// tunable
const NUMTHREADS: i32 = 4;

fn f(val: i32) -> i32 {
    // expensive computation
    let res = val + 1;
    res
}

fn main() {
    // choose an odd number of elements
    let orig: Vec<i32> = (1..14).collect();

    let mut guards: Vec<JoinHandle<Vec<i32>>> = vec!();

    // split into slices
    for chunk in orig.chunks(orig.len() / NUMTHREADS as usize) {
        let chunk = chunk.to_owned();
        let g = thread::spawn(move || chunk.into_iter().map(f).collect());
        guards.push(g);
    };

    // collect the results
    let mut result: Vec<i32> = Vec::with_capacity(orig.len());
    for g in guards {
        result.extend(g.join().unwrap().into_iter());
    }

    println!("Flattened result: {:?}", result);
}
```

Comment: Would you mind if I updated this answer to use crossbeam or scoped_threadpool? Of course, you are welcome to update it yourself, if you'd prefer.

Comment: Sure, go ahead. Unfortunately, I don't think I have enough time to do it...

Comment: For people finding this now: `thread::scoped` has been removed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121250/consume-non-overlapping-vector-chunks-and-combine-results