# Threaded code crashes calling FFI process

Tags: python, multithreading, rust, ffi

I've converted a function to use threads (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31123137/416626)). It behaves as expected in tests (that is, it returns identical values to the non-threaded version). However, calling it from Python using `ctypes` causes the calling process to crash.

First, the working function:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn convert_vec(lon: Array, lat: Array) -> Array {
    // snip
    // orig is a Vec<(f32, f32)>
    // convert is a conversion function
    let result: Vec<(i32, i32)> = orig.iter()
        .map(|elem| convert(elem.0, elem.1))
        .collect();
    // convert back to vector of unsigned integer Tuples
    let nvec = result.iter()
        .map(|ints| Tuple { a: ints.0 as u32, b: ints.1 as u32 })
        .collect();
    Array::from_vec(nvec)
}
```

And now the threaded version, which passes tests (using `cargo test`) but crashes when called from Python:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn convert_vec_threaded(lon: Array, lat: Array) -> Array {
    // snip
    // orig is a Vec<(f32, f32)>
    // convert is a conversion function
    let mut guards: Vec<JoinHandle<Vec<(i32, i32)>>> = vec!();
    // split into slices
    for chunk in orig.chunks(orig.len() / NUMTHREADS as usize) {
        let chunk = chunk.to_owned();
        let g = thread::spawn(move || chunk
            .into_iter()
            .map(|elem| convert(elem.0, elem.1))
            .collect());
        guards.push(g);
    }
    let mut result: Vec<(i32, i32)> = Vec::with_capacity(orig.len());
    for g in guards {
        result.extend(g.join().unwrap().into_iter());
    }
    // convert back to vector of unsigned integer Tuples
    let nvec = result.iter()
        .map(|ints| Tuple { a: ints.0 as u32, b: ints.1 as u32 })
        .collect();
    Array::from_vec(nvec)
}
```

The complete testable example is available [here](https://github.com/urschrei/rust_bng)

Comment: What does the crash look like? I would not use .unwrap(), since a rust panic inside a call from Python is a *very bad idea*.

Comment: The crash I get in ipython is: `thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'assertion failed: size != 0', /private/tmp/rust20150626-13301-uiklsd/rustc-1.1.0/src/libcore/slice.rs:196
fatal runtime error: Could not unwind stack, error = 5
Illegal instruction: 4`

Comment: Ok that assertion looks like you are passing `.chunks(0)` actually. Could it be as simple as that?

Comment: I don't follow…you mean am I passing it a zero-sized chunk?

Comment: `.chunks(orig.len() / NUMTHREADS as usize)`  ← argument must not be zero

Comment: Oh for god's sake. That's what it is. So I just need to guard for the possibility of input < NUMTHREADS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message it looks like you used a chunk size of `0` for some inputs. `[T]::chunks(size)` will assert that `size != 0`.

If we want `NUMTHREADS` chunks, we could split it like this:

```
// Divide into NUMTHREADS chunks
let mut size = orig.len() / NUMTHREADS;
if orig.len() % NUMTHREADS > 0 { size += 1; }
// If we want to avoid the case where orig.len() == 0, we need another adjustment:
size = std::cmp::max(1, size);
```